# How to render (redrawn) usercontrol when binding property source changed in windows phone

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, user-controls

I build a control in Windows Phone (same WPF) draw a vertical chart by timeline.
In Xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MiO2.CustomControls.VerticalChart"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480"
         xmlns:blockPivot="clr-namespace:MiO2.Framework"
         x:Name="uc">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="animateOpacityPointer">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="pointer">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" blockPivot:BlocksPan.IsEnabled="True" Background="{Binding Background, ElementName=uc}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="renderLayer" Grid.Row="1">
        <Canvas x:Name="canvasRender">

        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="10" x:Name="touchLayer"  Visibility="Visible">
        <Canvas x:Name="pointerLayer" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <Grid Width="52" x:Name="pointer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="tbTime" Height="40" Margin="0,0,0,0" Foreground="Black" />

                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <Ellipse Fill="#FF8BE0FB" Height="40" Width="40" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            <Ellipse Fill="#FF01ADF5" Height="20" Width="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Grid>
                        <Line x:Name="line" Stroke="Black" StrokeDashArray="4 2" Y2="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Canvas>

        <TextBlock x:Name="tbUnit" Text="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="Black" />
        <Slider blockPivot:BlocksPan.IsEnabled="True" ManipulationCompleted="touchLayer_ManipulationCompleted" ManipulationStarted="touchLayer_ManipulationStarted" Background="Transparent" ManipulationDelta="touchLayer_ManipulationDelta" Foreground="Transparent" Style="{StaticResource SliderStyle1}">

        </Slider>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

In code behide:

```
public partial class VerticalChart : UserControl
{
    public VerticalChart()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += VerticalChart_Loaded;
    }

    void VerticalChart_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeChart();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemSource", typeof(IEnumerable<ITimelineData>), typeof(VerticalChart), 
        new PropertyMetadata(null, ItemSourcePropertyChangedCallback));

    private static void ItemSourcePropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<ITimelineData> ItemSource
    {
        get { return base.GetValue(ItemSourceProperty) as IEnumerable<ITimelineData>; }
        set { base.SetValue(ItemSourceProperty, value); }
    }
    Random ran = new Random();
    double unit = 0;
    double leftStart = 0;

    public void InitializeChart()
    {
        if (ItemSource.Count() == 0) return;

        TimeSpan period = ItemSource.Last().TimeEnd - ItemSource.First().TimeStart;
        double width = this.ActualWidth - pointer.ActualWidth / 2;
        double height = renderLayer.ActualHeight;
        double minutes = period.TotalMinutes;
        leftStart = pointer.ActualWidth / 2;

        double divide = (width / minutes);
        if (divide >= 2) unit = 2;
        else if (divide >= 1) unit = 1;
        else if (divide >= 0.5) unit = 0.5;
        else if (divide >= 0.25) unit = 0.25;
        else unit = 0.1;
        tbUnit.Text = unit.ToString();

        foreach (ITimelineData used in ItemSource)
        {
            double min = (used.TimeEnd - used.TimeStart).TotalMinutes;
            int borderWidth = (int)(unit * min);
            double left = (used.TimeStart - ItemSource.First().TimeStart).TotalMinutes * unit + leftStart;

            Border border = new Border();
            border.Width = borderWidth;
            border.Height = ran.Next(100, 250);

            Binding binding = new Binding("Foreground");
            binding.Source = this;
            border.SetBinding(Border.BackgroundProperty, binding);

            double top = height - border.Height;
            Canvas.SetLeft(border, left);
            Canvas.SetTop(border, top);
            canvasRender.Children.Add(border);
        }
    }
}
```

And use in Mainpage.xaml

```
<myControl:VerticalChart ItemSource="{Binding ActivitiesToday}" />
```

And when property `ActivitiesToday` changed means `ItemSource` property updated. And I want, **when ItemSource updated new or change number collection `Cavas: renderLayer` redrawn number of `Border` inside**. How to do that? I want to redrawn `Border` in `Canvas` when `ItemSource` updated.

For code draw list Border:

```
 Border border = new Border();
 border.Width = borderWidth;
 border.Height = ran.Next(100, 250);

 Binding binding = new Binding("Foreground");
 binding.Source = this;
 border.SetBinding(Border.BackgroundProperty, binding);

 double top = height - border.Height;
 Canvas.SetLeft(border, left);
 Canvas.SetTop(border, top);
 canvasRender.Children.Add(border);
```

How to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a custom event in your usercontrol

   ```
   private event ItemsSourceChanged;
   ```
2. Add all the required code to support event change
3. Now trigger the event on property change.

   ```
   public IEnumerable<ITimelineData> ItemSource
   {
       get { return base.GetValue(ItemSourceProperty) as IEnumerable<ITimelineData>; }
       set { base.SetValue(ItemSourceProperty, value); OnItemSourcePropertyChange(); }
   }
   ```
4. In xaml, map the event to code-behind and do your changes.

   ```
   <myControl:VerticalChart ItemSource="{Binding ActivitiesToday}" ItemSourceChanged="doSomething" />
   ```